# How can I work with cm units in illustrator CC extendscript?

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

I would like to draw a simple rectangle in cm.

So far I have done that :

```
var units = 4; 
app.preferences.setIntegerPreference("rulerType", units);
app.preferences.setIntegerPreference("strokeUnits", units)
```

And indeed when I check in edit/preferences/unit menu, it shows units in cm

But When I draw a rectangle :

```
var rectangle1 = doc.pathItems.rectangle(posTop, posLeft, myWidth, myHeight);
```

myWidth and myHeight don't fit the cm rules.

Any help ?

thanks

Fransua

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution :

```
var ptToCm = 0.0353;
myWidth/=ptToCm;
myHeight/=ptToCm;
```